# Python manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have 3 same models`(M1,M2,M3)` each for 5 customers`(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)` and now I came to know from my business that for each customer one model has been chosen by them. The models chosen for the customer could be seen in `Best_Models` dataframe. Now I have to select the result of the best model that has been chosen by the business for each customer, which can be seen in Output data frame, How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'x1': [86,23,32,13,45,12],
        'x2': [96,98,34,12,22,19], 
        'x3': [56,23,44,12,32,33],
        'x4': [96,43,84,72,42,97],
        'x5': [16,33,64,82,92,44]
       }

Model1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, 
                     columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']
                    )


data2 = {'x1': [36,23,32,13,66,12],
        'x2': [56,98,64,12,22,19], 
        'x3': [86,23,44,52,32,33],
        'x4': [96,43,74,72,42,97],
        'x5': [16,53,64,82,77,44]
       }

Model2 = pd.DataFrame(data1, 
                     columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'])


data3 = {'x1': [36,43,32,13,66,12],
        'x2': [56,48,64,12,22,19], 
        'x3': [86,23,44,54,32,33],
        'x4': [96,44,74,44,42,97],
        'x5': [16,53,64,82,44,44]
       }

Model3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, 
                     columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'])
Model3



data4 = {"Customer":["x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"],
         "Best_Model":["M2","M3","M1","M2","M3"]
       }

Best_Models = pd.DataFrame(data4, columns=['Customer', 'Best_Model'])
Best_Models

data5 = {'x1': [36,23,32,13,66,12],
        'x2': [56,48,64,12,22,19], 
        'x3': [56,23,44,12,32,33],
        'x4': [96,43,74,72,42,97],
        'x5': [16,53,64,82,44,44]
       }

Output = pd.DataFrame(data5, 
                     columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'], 
                     index=['I1', 'I2','I3','I4','I5','I6'])
Output
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to do the pivot of the best models dataframe and then map the results but that did not work for me, could anyone suggest me a better way to code this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `concat` then using `loc`:

```
(pd.concat([Model1,Model2,Model3], keys=['M1','M2','M3'], axis=1)
   .loc[:,[(m,c) for m,c in zip(Best_Models.Best_Model, Best_Models.Customer)]]
)
```

Output:

```
   M2  M3  M1  M2  M3
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
0  86  56  56  96  16
1  23  48  23  43  53
2  32  64  44  84  64
3  13  12  12  72  82
4  45  22  32  42  44
5  12  19  33  97  44
```

Comment: how to handle error exceptional handling in above case , suppose a customer has a best model M2 and the column of that customer is missing in model M2, then instead of throwing error and program to end I want program to move to next customer instead of throwing error

Answer (score 0):

```
Best_Models.apply(lambda r: 
                  {'M1': Model1, 'M2': Model2, 'M3': Model3}[
                      r['Best_Model']][r['Customer']], axis=1).T.rename(
                    columns=Best_Models.Customer)
```

output:

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
0   86  56  56  96  16
1   23  48  23  43  53
2   32  64  44  84  64
3   13  12  12  72  82
4   45  22  32  42  44
5   12  19  33  97  44
```

- Create a dictionary to map best model names to the actual Model.
- Since customers names in the best_models and the Models match we can directly index them
- Finally rename the result with the corresponding customer names.

Comment: how to handle error exceptional handling in above case , suppose a customer has a best model M2 and the column of  that customer is missing in model M2, then instead of throwing error and program to end I want program to move to next customer instead of throwing error